# Etymology of "exterior" in "exterior calculus"

Tags: soft-question, ho.history-overview, exterior-algebra, etymology

What is the origin of the term "exterior" in "exterior calculus"? How does this term relate to "interior products" and "inner products", if it does at all?

Comment: Looks like an E&LU quesuion.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think it's well known to have been introduced by **Grassmann**. He explains the word choice in *Die lineale Ausdehnungslehre* [(1844, pp. x-xi)](https://archive.org/stream/dielinealeausde00grasgoog#page/n15):

> I have shown how one can understand as product of two segments the parallelogram (...); this product is distinguished in that factors can only be interchanged with a sign change, while at the same time the product of two parallel segments vanishes. This concept stood in contrast to another (...) Namely when I projected one segment perpendicularly onto another, then the arithmetic product of this projection with the segment projected upon represented likewise a product of the two, insofar as the distributive relation with addition also held. But that product was of a whole other kind than the first, as its factors were interchanged without sign change, and the product of two perpendicular segments vanished. ***I named the former product exterior, the latter interior,*** reflecting that the former was nonzero only when involving independent directions, the latter only when involving a shared i.e. partly common one.

and again in the second edition [(1862, p. 51)](https://archive.org/stream/dieausdehnugsle00grasgoog#page/n69):

> I chose the name ***exterior multiplication*** to emphasize that the product is only nonzero when one factor lies entirely outside the span of the other. Exterior multiplication stands in contrast with the interior one (chap. 4).

Comment: So, just to fill in a step you’ve omitted, that’s maybe not obvious to all readers: Grassmann’s original contrast is between the *interior* and *exterior* products of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ — aka the dot-product and cross-product.  The former of these was later generalised to “inner products”, etc; the later was generalised to “exterior algebra”, etc.

Comment: So it seems that first the pair "inner product" and "outer product" was conceived, but these two terms separated later. The term "interior product" for the contraction with a vector field in differential geometry is then most likely a later innovation because the "exterior product" had no sibling anymore.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine : Yes, if by "later" you mean "on a later page of the same book". (Just leaf through, e.g. exterior at the 1862 link above, and interior at [ibid., p. 107](https://archive.org/stream/dieausdehnugsle00grasgoog#page/n125).)